# Windows Phone Project Load Failed

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, project, solution

I have a solution that include 3 Windows phone project. When I get them from TFS, 2 project is running correct but the main project is giving error. What should I do?

Extra note : Main project has service reference.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Did you try reloading the Project and the solution? Take a look over [here](http://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/1220)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e60bc3dc-b3b0-416b-bacc-a9534b7ce99c/reversi-sample-the-project-requires-user-input-reload-the-project-for-more-information?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: of course, I have done but didn't solve it.

Comment: Try adding the solution to the source control. I guess you'll find an option called `Add Solution to Source Control` in the Source Control. Then give a check in and see.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you are loading a solution with 2 portable class libraries and 1 windows phone 8 project.  Can you create a new phone project and open it?